# Clicking Specific button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a particular button with Selenium in Python, but am having trouble identifying that particular button. For example, if I was on the google page of [this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ignominious), and I wanted to have the translation bar drop down, how would I go about referencing that specific element. Inspecting it in my browser I see some of what I assume to be its data as:

```
    <div style="clear: both;" aria-controls="uid_0" aria-expanded="false"
     class="_LJ _qxg xpdarr _WGh vk_arc" data-fbevent="fastbutton" jsaction="kx.t;
 fastbutton: kx.t" role="button" tabindex="0" data-ved="0ahUKEwiwn-6K17XLAhVLWD4KHTk9CTkQmDMILzAA">
```

However, from this point I'm not sure how I would use the find element by functions to reference what I need to in order to call it properly.

```
driver.find_element_by_*("?").click()

import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#comment
print ("Let's talk about Python.")


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://www.google.com")

assert "Google" in driver.title

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

elem.send_keys("ignominious")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.find_element_by_*("?").click()


assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `css_selector` with the class attribute

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._LJ._qxg.xpdarr._WGh.vk_arc").click()
```

Or `class_name` with any one of the classes

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("_LJ").click()
# or
driver.find_element_by_class_name("_qxg").click()
# or
driver.find_element_by_class_name("xpdarr").click()
# or
driver.find_element_by_class_name("_WGh").click()
# or
driver.find_element_by_class_name("vk_arc").click()
```

Sending click to the element child will also work

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("vk_ard").click()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. I tried that but it didn't seem to work, I'll edit my post to show all of my code so far in case its something else.

Comment: Yes the error I get is too long for a comment, here it is: http://pastebin.com/07JRHd6W

Comment: @TheOneTrueSign My bad, it should be `driver.find_element_by_class_name("_WGh")` and `driver.find_element_by_class_name("vk_arc")`. I fixed the answer and added one more option

Comment: Thanks, but sadly none of these are making the translation tab drop down. Could an issue be somewhere else in my code?

Comment: @TheOneTrueSign the error before was that you don't ave class name `_WGh.vk_arc`. Are you still trying `driver.find_element_by_class_name("_WGh.vk_arc")`?

Comment: I switched it to `driver.find_element_by_class_name("_WGh").click()` now.

Comment: @TheOneTrueSign try to add `implicit_wait` after you create the new driver `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`

Comment: Yes! That made it work! What units is 10 in? Thanks so much for working through this with me.

Comment: @TheOneTrueSign Its seconds. It will look for the elemnts up to 10 seconds every time you do `driver.find_element()`. You can increase or decrease the time of course.

Answer (score 1):

For a better maintainability you should try to work with ids.

With your example the selector would be:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#uid_1 > div[role='button']").click()
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, however for me that code doesn't seem to make the drop down bar expand. Maybe it is a problem somewhere else in my code?

Comment: Sorry about that, I took the wrong id. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that works. If I may ask, I see where you got "#uid_1" But where did you get "> div[role='button']" from. Is that standard to include after you enter the id?

Comment: I got the div[role='button'] from the element where the mouse is supposed to click. It's an attribute selector (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). And yes it's common practice to use a combinator after an id.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to click on arrow.
If yes then below code is working for me:-

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("ignominious");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

    driver.findElement(By.className("vk_ard")).click();
```

Hope it will help you :)